# In kivy, kv file in scrollview I do not know what is the error it just says "invalid syntax" :( but according to me its right

Tags: kivy

here is a simple code but it do not work
Error is comming on size_hint on scrollview section in kv file

```
#main.py
class stklay(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(1,56):
            size = dp(100)
            b = Button(text = str(i),size_hint = (None,None),size = (size,size))
            self.add_widget(b)

class BLApp(App):
    pass

BLApp().run()

#BL.kv
scrollvw:

<stklay>:

<scrollvw@ScrollView>:
    stklay:
        size_hint: 1, None#error is here
        height: self.minimum_height
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `kv` expects class names to be capitalized. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#syntax-of-a-kv-file).

So try changing your `kv` to:

```
#BL.kv
Scrollvw:

<Stklay>:

<Scrollvw@ScrollView>:
    Stklay:
        size_hint: 1, None#error is here
        height: self.minimum_height
```

and in your `py`:

```
class Stklay(StackLayout):
```